# when we can use freak out?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am not sure about the usage of freak out - it means wildly irrational behaviour?
Can we say for example that when someone is not doing something like expected is freaking out? I will give you an example. I have a colleague who is extremely kind and gentle to me and I am considering this as suspicious , can I say he is freaking me out?

Comment: Forgive my joke ... I suggest you ask a psychiatrist rather than a linguist for the answer to that question. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different uses of 'freak out':

1. Intransitive verb (no object) - to freak out - meaning to suddenly behave oddly, or in an uninhibited fashion, or to get very angry or excited, or worried.
2. Transitive verb (with object) - to freak someone out - meaning to cause someone else to behave as above.

The verb is considered very informal and conversational and not suitable for formal or academic writing.

[Freak out (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/freak-someone-out)

[Freak out (Collins)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/freak-out)

Comment: Very informal but perfectly correct.